# Is the "Access to content" value from the Xbox One settings available through the Javascript UWP api?

Tags: javascript, uwp, xbox-one

We're developing a UWP application for Xbox One. We'd like to filter content within the application, by checking the current user's content restrictions.

We were hoping to be able to get a lower age rating for our application by filtering any content above the user's `Access to content` setting, which can be found at `Settings->Account->Content restrictions->Access to content`. However, we can't find any properties representing this setting in the Javascript api.

Is it possible to retrieve the value of this setting from the Javascript UWP platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and experimenting I was finally able to find a solution:

```
Windows.Media.ContentRestrictions.RatedContentRestrictions()
    .getBrowsePolicyAsync()
    .then(function (result) {
        /* 
         * "result" contains a ContentRestrictionsBrowsePolicy object which 
         * provides all the information I need.
         */
    });
```

Have a look at the [ContentRestrictionsBrowsePolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.contentrestrictions.contentrestrictionsbrowsepolicy) class for more information.